# Serial upvoting

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

Please see my reputation changes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674374/mithunsatheesh?tab=reputation).

Yesterday someone serially upvoted all my questions at around 11:46 to 11:57. Seeing which I stopped answering any more questions as all those would go reversed as a whole. Today all those got reversed and I got a -165 an hour ago.

Now guess what, again it started up voting this time with my answers (*just 15 mins after the reversal happened*). My question is that it is the second time the same thing is happening to me in less than a day. So it seems the action is  really intentional. Can't we think of actually disabling the account which is intentionally causing this?

I am sure that it is not any one who saw my answers helpful upvoting me because he would take sometime in understanding the questions or answers he is upvoting so that it won't be 5-6 upvotes per sec.

Comment: Serial voting can be done from different users. Also the user who is serially voting you gets a message from the moderator to avoid doing so in future. But not sure when does user get message from the moderator (e.g. after 1 time, 2 times etc..). And if user continue serial voting, he is suspended for some period.

Comment: @hims Reversed serial voting will not alert any moderator. Unless the user contacts them or posts on Meta about it, this can go unnoticed a couple of times before any action is taken

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The user involved in this activity has been warned, and hopefully will stop the serial voting.

> Seeing which i stopped answering any more questions as all those would go reversed as a whole.

You don't need to stop answering. When the bad votes get reversed, your reputation will be recalculated and anything you missed out on due to those votes you will regain elsewhere, if applicable. Don't let serial voting stop you from participating.

See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)